# Internal Modifier on an Interface's Property

Tags: c#, .net, properties, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IAgable {
    int Age { get; internal set; }
}
```

I want the `Age` property, to be **read-only** for external assemblies that reference this interface, but also I want the `Age` property to be set on the interface's same assembly, hence the `internal` modifier.

This, however, seems to throw a compilation error, as **accessibility modifiers may not be used on accessors in an interface**.

I want the property to be called from an interface, and I want to be able to set it at an internal level. At the same time, if referenced from an outside project, I want it to be readonly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Ommit the set on the interface and put the internal set on the implementation types.

Comment: @asawyer If I take out the `internal set` from the interface, then I have to downcast the interface to its implementation to be able to set the property. I don't want that.

Comment: You'll want to use an abstract base type instead of an interface then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# internal interface with internal implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117386/c-sharp-internal-interface-with-internal-implementation)

Comment: @asawyer He doesn't want to provide an implementation, so no.

Comment: I understand that I'm going against the concept of an interface here. But maybe there is a clean way to accomplish this without using abstract classes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have an internal interface that provides both a `get` and a `set`, and a public interface that provides only a `get`.  Have the public interface extend the internal interface:

```
public interface IAgable
{
    int Age { get; }
}

internal interface IAgableInternal : IAgable
{
    int Age { set; }
}
```

Comment: This was my plan B. I was really trying to avoid having to create another interface just to set a property. But I guess it's the only way :P

Comment: @MatiCicero Why would it be a problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `internal interface IAgableInternal : IAgable`?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible according to Microsoft

Interfaces declared directly within a namespace can be declared as public or internal and, just like classes and structs, interfaces default to internal access. Interface members are always public because the purpose of an interface is to enable other types to access a class or struct. No access modifiers can be applied to interface members.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand better the true concept of an interface

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public interface IAgeable {
 MyAge {get;set}
}
public class MyAge:IAgeable{
   public MyAge(int age){
       MyAge = age;
  }
   int MyAge { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: This does not throw a compilation error if an external assembly tries to set `MyAge` from the interface

Comment: The MYAge class is public, it would be included in the assembly and anyone using your interface would have to follow the pattern of creating a new instance by passing in the age parm. (Unless of course they wanted a null object)

Comment: Won't work in my case because my implementations are internal and hidden from external assemblies. The external assembly just calls a factory for the instance creations.

Comment: Then you will have to change your design as the interface by definition will not allow modifiers.  You could set up an base class that is inherited instead, as there are no restrictions on that. Or as posted have two interfaces, the problem is that you can never get a private set from an Interface def.

Comment: You can also set MyAge to private.